# Anchor links working locally but not when deployed (React)

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a one page react app and I have a menu with anchor links set up like this:

`<a href="/App#story" class="font-medium text-gray-100 hover:text-red-600">Story</a>`

And in the target div, I have it like this:

`<div id="story" class="py-16 xl:py-36 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 bg-black overflow-hidden">`

When I do `npm start` to run the page locally, the anchor links work as intended. When I deploy it to the web, the links give me a 404.

Why would this happen?

EDIT:
I read about `react-router-dom` and tried to implement it, but I am getting strange behavior.

1. I imported this at the top of App.js:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
```

2. I wrapped the enter contents of the first App() function in `<Router></Router>`.
3. Then inside the App() section, I set up this:

```
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
```

4. My About link is set up like this:

```
<a href="/about" class="text-base text-gray-300 hover:text-white">
                          About
                        </a>
```

5. Then at the very bottom of the App.js document, below the  , I have this:

```
function About() {
  return ( 
  <><h2>About</h2>
  <br />
  <p>Test</p></>
  );
}
```

But what happens when I click the About link is it re-renders the entire main page and the text "About Test" at the bottom.

[image: screenshot]

What do I need to do to get this to render as an entirely new page?

Comment: You have to use °react-router-dom`

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: When you deploy is the app running at root level like server.com/App or is it hosted with path like server.com/foo/App? anchor tag will be taking to ${location.origin}/App

Comment: You say that you set up the `<Switch>` segment inside the App() section. Did you by any chance have the entire main page *outside* of that <Switch> tag? Because if you did, that sounds like it could be the problem. Changing the route by clicking a <Link> only changes the content that's inside of a <Switch> tag, so to only display your main page if the about page isn't shown, try something like
`<Switch>
<Route path="/about">
<About />
</Route>
<Route path="/">
<MainPage />
</Route>
</Switch>`
or something.

Comment: @olafmoriarty - thanks. I think I follow your explanation, but where am I supposed to "define" `MainPage`? It won't compile without defining it somewhere, and the main "app" is called `App()`, and it seems to not make sense to define it in the way that I defined the About page. Am I missing something? Or is `App()` supposed to contain the Routers and every page is its own function?

Comment: @reallymemorable, `<MainPage />` was just an example, what I was trying to express was "put whatever you need to display on the main page in a `<Route>` at the bottom of the `<Switch>` statement. In my personal opinion, the code looks a lot cleaner if every page is its own function, but that's not a requirement, you can put your JSX code directly into the `<Route>`, too.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware you can not use `<a>` tags for internal navigation in react. I don't know why it works locally for you.

With react you are creating single page applications (SPAs), you have 1 html page that can be found in the public folder. If you created the app using `create-react-app`, you will see within it, an element such `<div id=root> </div>`. That is the targetted rendering location, where you will be rendering the entire app by dynamically changing the html within it as you interact with the page.

However, when you typically click on an `<a>` tag, we are usually taken to different html page. Here I would assume the server is trying to retrieve either the App.html page or index.html page from within public/App folder.

React does not typically come in with built in routing functions/components. It leaves it up to the user to implement. So user's usually turn to a package like `react-router` along with `react-router-dom/native` (depending on react or react native) to get those functionalities.

### Answer to Updated Question

Change your `<a>` tags to `<Links>` as follows

```js
<Link to='/about' className='tailwind_classes'>About</Link>
```

`<Link>` tags are meant to replace `<a>` tags if using react-router-dom for navigation.

When you click on it, your `<Router>` is notified and lets the `<Switch>` figure out which `<Route>` to render

### Update

Okay let's say you have a header where your links are, and we have 2 components `<Home>` and `<About>`

Then this is how your `<App>` should look like

```js
return(
  <Router>
    {/* The header can be it's own component*/}
    <header>
     <Link to='/home' className='tailwind_classes'>Home</Link>
     <Link to='/about' className='tailwind_classes'>About</Link>
    </header>
    <Switch>
     {/* exact makes sure path has to be exactly '/' */}
     <Route exact path="/">
       <Home />
     </Route>
     <Route path="/about">
       <About />
     </Route>
    </Switch>
  <Router>
)
```

You could obviously write the markup for the `<Home>` & `<About>` component directly inside the `<Route>`s but would not advise. The header can also be it's own component and it will always stay on the screen since it is outside the switch, making it kind of a global thing.

The to prop of Link must match the path prop of one of the Route

Basically when you click on a link, the url changes. The Router is notified who then passes the new url to the Switch, which then acts like a switch case statement to match the url and renders/mounts the JSX inside the matched Route after removing/unmounting what was previously there.

Read the read the [react-router-dom documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) for further clarification

Comment: Thanks! I updated my original post. I'm still a bit stuck.

Comment: I changed it to `<Link to='/about' class="text-base text-gray-300 hover:text-white">About</Link>` and am still getting the same behavior.